# Writing all Camera2 CaptureResults into a file

Tags: android, file, android-camera2

I am trying to export into a texte file all the parameters from an acquisition using `Camera2` API on `Android`. I figured out that they are all contained in the `CaptureCallback` but I just don't know how to parse them all and write them into a `file`.

```
private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback  = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback()
{

    private void process(CaptureResult result)
    {
        //parse and write as txt all available result keys and values
    }
}
```

It is probably an easy thing to do.

Comment: Well you could post semi code where we could see which keys and values you want to extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a piece of code that do the job. I open a file, parse all the keys and write the values into it :

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyApp");
File outputfile = new File(mediaStorageDir, "Camera_parameters.txt");
if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
    if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
        return;
    }
}
try {
    FileOutputStream m_outputstream = new FileOutputStream(outputfile);
    OutputStreamWriter m_stream = new OutputStreamWriter(m_outputstream);
    List<CaptureResult.Key<?>> keys = result.getKeys();
    for (CaptureResult.Key<?> key : keys) {
        Log.d(TAG, key + " has value " + result.get(key));
        m_stream.write(key + "\t" + result.get(key) + "\n");
    }
    m_stream.close();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
}
```